# Django: cretae new object with unique order

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a simplified model:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
```

How I can create a new object with existing order number? If I create a new object with an order number 6 for example, then previous 6 and higher orders should have their order number increased by one (7, 8, etc.). Another question is how I can reorder existing objects? Ideally, I could do it by drag and drop in admin but it should be also possible by typing new order number directly.

I have initially thousands of objects and reasonable maximum I can think of now should be less than 100,000. Normally I add new objects programmatically from JSON file and some individual changes can be done in admin.

I already tried to implement this with django-admin-sortable but no success so far. Also, I'm not sure if it can handle the case of programmatical insertion.

Comment: Have you tried `order = models.AutoField(primary_key=False)` and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a lot of records to process, I would not use a recursive method on the actual Django objects. It will take too much time. But I would override the save method, before saving the object and use an SQL command.

```
UPDATE Example SET order = order + 1 WHERE order >= 6.
```

Also remember to handle the delete situation of the object in order 6, after you delete the object.

```
UPDATE Example SET order = order - 1 WHERE order > 6.
```

Edit 1:

Django has an expression called F() [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F). You can use it in you case like this:

```
from django.db.models import F 
Example.objects.filter(order__gte=self.order).update(order=F('order')+1)
```

Through this Django creates an update query, which is executed. It doesn't hit the database for every object.

Edit 2:
For example:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from django.db.models import F
        Example.objects.filter(order__gte=self.order).update(order=F('order') + 1)
        super(Example, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This sounds right, how I can make this happen? I'm not familiar with raw SQL. For example in save(), is it possible to do like --> Example.objects.filter(order__gte=self.order).update(order=order+1) and then calling super().save()? Obviously order+1 doesn't work in my example since order is not defined. I should somehow get the order value from the filtered queryset.

Comment: If you will experience speed issues, I should start looking into RAW sql queries. But if it is enough for your system, then I would recommend using Django provided functions, as they represent less complexity for your code.

Comment: What do you mean by Django provided functions? Could you add simple example how you would do this in practice? I don't think speed is really an issue since the order is only changed by admin, not by users. Thus, users won't see any difference.

Comment: I mean functions which exists in Django. For example, check Edit 2.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly with save and delete but this can't handle update. It's little trickier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

you have to override to save method in model, if your order number is 6 you have to pull all the records from 6 to n where n is the highest order number, you have to increment +1 to  the existing order number from n to 6 in reverse order once is done now u can save for the new object with order number 6

Comment: Yes, that's something I thought also but it's not optimal in the case of I just swap an order of two adjacent elements etc. I supposed that there would be some existing solutions for this since this is a quite popular use case I think.